# Memory Management in iOS without using navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I am new to iOS development and learning it on my own for the last month. I made a simple application in which I opted simple approach of connecting two view controllers with a segue to go forward and then coming back to same with `dismissViewController`.

When I go from one view to my second view memory usage in Xcode simulator increases from 15MB to 20MB but when I return to first it does not become 15MB (it is still around 19.5 MB). I have already gone through many answers and tried them nothing is working.

Given below is my code of second view controller. Please suggest something.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AboutUsView : ViewController {
    //var loginScreenView: HomeScreenView!
    var imageview = UIImageView()
    var SwiftTimer : NSTimer?
    var SwiftCounter = 0
    var images: [String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        images = ["abt1", "abt2", "abt3", "abt4"]

        let homeButton = self.view.addHeaderToView()
        homeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToHomePage), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.addPicture(images!)
        self.addLabelHeader("About us")
        self.addLabelBody("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting")
    }

    @IBAction func goToHomePage(homeButton: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        SwiftTimer?.invalidate()

        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func addPicture(images:[String]) {
        // screen width and height

        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0.1*height, width, 0.4*height))
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "abt1")

        SwiftTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target:self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        // you can change the content mode:

        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
    }

    func updateCounter() {
        SwiftCounter = (SwiftCounter < 0 ? (images!.count - 1) : SwiftCounter % images!.count )

        imageview.image = UIImage(named: images![SwiftCounter++])
    }

    func addLabelHeader(labelText:String) {
        // screen width and height:

        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let logoLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.05 * width, 0.52*height, 0.5*width, 0.05*height))
        logoLabel.text = labelText
        logoLabel.textColor = (UIColor.blackColor())
        logoLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(24.0)

        self.view.addSubview(logoLabel)
    }

    func addLabelBody(labelText:String) {
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let logoLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.05 * width, 0.52*height, 0.9*width, 0.35*height))
        logoLabel.text = labelText
        logoLabel.textColor = (UIColor.blackColor())
        logoLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)
        logoLabel.numberOfLines = 10
        self.view.addSubview(logoLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to have any problem, try print something in `deinit` and see if it got called

Comment: I agree with @Tj3n. A timer can certainly cause this issue, but you are remembering to invalidate your timer. You might try setting `SwiftTimer` to nil after invalidating and see if that helps. But please, please, delete this line: `self.view.removeFromSuperview()`. That is totally wrong!

Comment: Yeah you should never remove the `self.view` of any `UIViewController`. Also from this file it is not visible. Can you show the other file from where you are Pushing/Showing `AboutUsView`.

Comment: Did you write the addHeaderToView() method? If yes, could you post the code. I'm trying to reproduce your memory issue but the code you posted here seems to work fine.

Comment: Confirm (either via Instruments' "Allocations" tool or Xcode 8's "Debug Memory Graph" tool (as described in WWDC 2016 [Visual Debugging with Xcode 8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/)) what is accounting for this memory. It's not clear whether the problem is view controller not getting deallocated or something else (e.g. if you call `UIImage(named:)`, those images get cached and won't be released until there is memory pressure). There's not enough here to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Hi Matt , I have removed that line but can you suggest me harm with that line because code just runs fine .  Guillaume Legrain , yes I have written addHeaderToView method in extension of UIVIEW and since it is common to all my pages I am calling it. if you want I can post code for that

Comment: The timer is a common source of these sorts of problems, but given that you `invalidate` it in `viewWillDisappear`, it's unlikely to be the problem here (though it could be if you accidentally called `addPicture` twice, which you don't here). You need to confirm _what_ is taking up the memory that is being consumed before you proceed to _how_ to fix it. E.g. temporarily comment out the `UIImage(named:)` and see if it's the caching of images that is consuming the memory.